# Using jQuery Tablesorter and divs in the cells not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I am using `<div>` to get the data into each cell.

I recently found out about `jQuery` `tablesorter` and tried to implement it with no luck.

I have this at the beginning of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#data_fm_op").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0]] }); 
});
```

and I am getting an error saying:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR
3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8) Timestamp: Mon, 24 Jun 2013 16:41:24 UTC

Message: 'config.parsers' is null or not an object Line: 600 Char: 21
Code: 0 URI: file:jquery.tablesorter.js
```

and I am creating each cell using the following function:

```
function addRow(tableID, nbrColumn) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    for(i = 0; i < nbrColumn; i++)
    {
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.contentEditable = true;
        var element = document.createElement("div");
        element.className = "boxes";
        element.id = tableID + n + "" + i;
        element.contentEditable = true;
        element.style.display = "inline";
        cell.id = tableID + n + "" + i + "cell";
        cell.appendChild(element);
    }
    n++;    
}
```

This function is used in a loop that creates a new row when it reads the data from the database so a new row is created and then all the data goes in each `<div>`.

Why is this error happening? and how can I fix this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Here is the code where I load the table:

```
function loadTables()
{
    loadTbl('fm_op', 'data_fm_op', 15);
    alert("sorter() WILL LOAD NOW");
    $(function sorter() 
    { 
        $("#data_fm_op").trigger("update").trigger("sorton", [[0, 1], [1, 0]]);
    }); 
}
```

This function is called in the onload of the `<body>` tag

**UPDATE**

```
<TABLE id="data_fm_op" class="table" >
        <thead><tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th><div id="data_fm_op000" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center;">T<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s"></span></div></th>
            <th style="display:none"><div id="data_fm_op001" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center">Status</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op002" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center">ID</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op003" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center">System</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op004" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center">Desc</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op005" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Resp</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op006" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center">Hrs</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op007" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Ingr</div></th>
            <th style="display:none"><div id="data_fm_op008" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Ini Real</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op009" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Ini</div></th>
            <th style="display:none"><div id="data_fm_op0010" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Beta Real</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op0011" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Beta</div></th>
            <th style="display:none"><div id="data_fm_op0012" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Prod Real</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op0013" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Prod</div></th>
            <th><div id="data_fm_op0014" type="text" style="color:#333;text-align:center" >Obs</div></th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </TABLE>
```

Comment: Is the table empty when the page loads? I'm wondering if your table doesn't have any <th> cells for tablesorter to initialize with on document ready.

Comment: @bbird the table starts with the <thead> with the respective <th> and their labels when the page loads. It also loads the rest of the table when the page loads but it calls a function for that.

Comment: Would this example help you ? -> http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html or if it's empty -> http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-empty-table.html

Comment: @Fabi the problem is that I am getting the data from a mySQL DB and I'm not using ajax. The cell is being generated using the function mentioned above

Comment: can u post part of the generated table?

Comment: @Fabi it's just a table with `<table><thead><th></th>...<th></th></th></thead><tbody></tbody></table>` nothing really special about it except for the way I am getting the cells populated (which is exactly why I am getting trouble with the tablesorter)

Comment: I was just wondering why it's not sorting, but if what maximus tells you doesnt work, it might be how your table is being generated

Comment: @Fabi what maximus said is not working :(

Comment: I think it'd help to post part of the generated code with maximus suggestion.. if you dont see any errors on the console anymore

Comment: @randomizertech you're creating a div type=text? 
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.type = "text";

Comment: @Fabi that was old code, it wasn't doing anything. I just erased it

Comment: @randomizertech I just updated my answer with a Fiddle, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting as an answer because I can't format my comment, but if it doesn't work, I'll delete it.

Have you tried calling the update by itself (see below) right after the loadTbl function?

```
function loadTables(){
    loadTbl('fm_op','data_fm_op',15);
    alert("sorter() WILL LOAD NOW");
    $("#data_fm_op").trigger("update").trigger("sorton",[[0,1], [1,0]]);
}
```

I've created a [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CX5MT/1/) for you, not sure if that's what youre going for.

Comment: Yes, I did try, but nothing happened :/

Comment: @randomizertech did you checkout the fiddle?

Comment: Ok what I want is similar. You are using input fields, I am using <div>'s and each div has a innerHTML with the value of the record in the Database

Comment: I used text inputs cause I thought thats what you wanted - but you can create anything you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess what I can do is save everything into an array and then use those values to create the row

Comment: the easier way would be for u to create an example fiddle like I did,because theres not enough data to determine the problem..

Comment: I am trying to re create your fiddle with <div>'s instead of the input but it doesnt work. Let's say you have <div>'s in both column and I want to sort that, is that possible? Instead of having 1 input and 1 just simple text?

Comment: What's the content of your divs? I updated to simple divs with text inside -> http://fiddle.jshell.net/CX5MT/3/

Comment: The content inside the divs is the data from the DB. The problem is how I am creating the cells. I think it has to be done using `var html = "<tr><td id='"+tableID+i+"cell'><div class='boxes' id='"+tableID+i+"'>"+tableID+i+"</div></td><td>"+i+"</td></tr>"` and I am using `cell.appendChild(element);`

Comment: well im not sure what your function insertCell does but I assume it's a single tr row..but there must be something going funky in the process thats why I asked you to get the generated code, that way you can possibly see whats going wrong

Comment: the insertCell creates a <td> in an row or <tr> but I believe is not using the standard HTML, if I see the source of the HTML with the full table, it doesn't show me <td>'s and <tr>'s

Comment: You think you'll be able to create the table in fiddle using row.insertCell like I am doing it? I think that would help understand the problem, maybe is not possible to do it that way and use tablesorter

Comment: This might help you understand insertCell http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp

Comment: I mean im not sure what youre inserting because to me it looks like it wouldnt fit the table properly.. and as you stated, its not showing td/tr which explains why it's broken.. instead, you can just loop through your DB results and add them all in one function like I did in my fiddle..at least I find it a lot easier. You create the HTML code and append it to your table

Comment: I re created the table following the fiddle you sent, and I get the same error. Maybe my tablesorter.js file is corrupted?

Comment: I added some static data to it using the `var html` method and I get the same `config.parsers` error in line 600

Comment: I made it work, but it only sorts when I click the header of the first column. It still give me the error though :(

Comment: try cleaning up your headers - use only <th>header</th> and add the styling you want by giving it a class or id as youre giving to the divs..

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating table rows dynamically you need to trigger 'update' and 'sorton' events on it after adding rows to make it work like this,

```
  $("#data_fm_op").trigger("update").trigger("sorton",[[0,0], [1,0]]);
```

check this out for more http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: This removed the error, but I am not able to sort the data on the table :/

Comment: you can try .trigger("sorton") instead of .trigger("sorton",[[0,0], [1,0]]). but make sure you call this right after the addition of row.

Comment: that will not going to help, as your table is not static. You have to call it right after it is fully constructed.

Comment: I did solved same problem in this way. If you list you html that can help, fiddle will be awsome.

Comment: I am using IE8, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't load the table in other browsers. I need it to work in IE8 though, so other browsers are irrelevant

Comment: can you do this for static tables without loadTbl function? It will clear if you have a problem with dynamic part or there is some other issue.

Comment: I just added two rows at the beginning and it does work, it sorts the rows but it takes the whole "dynamic" part as one big block, so it's either before the 2 static rows, or after depending on the sort

Comment: How can I put it in jsFiddle to get data from my (or any) database?

Comment: instead of fetching data put some hard coded data to show your logic

Comment: if I use hard coded data (static table), it works fine the problem is the way I am calling the data from the DB to populate the table (which is fine, untill I try to use tablesorter)

Comment: I'll ask you the same thing I asked Fabi, do uou think you'll be able to create the table in fiddle using row.insertCell like I am doing it? I think that would help understand the problem, maybe is not possible to do it that way and use tablesorter

Comment: something is wrong with your html code for sure. can you give the link to your side or inspect is your self?

Comment: what do u mean there is something wrong with the code? it works fine if I don't sort it, and now I've been asked to add the sorter on top of each column and it's not working with tablesorter

Comment: can you please please post final html, that will surely help?

Comment: what do u mean by the final html? like getting the source of the html page?

Comment: please see new update, that's all I get when I look at the source

Comment: I managed to recreate the table using Fabi's fiddle, but still when I see the source, there is no code for the rest of the rows, only the headers...